# “The books stacked”or “The books stacking”

Tags: grammar, gerunds

I'm totally confused.

> The books stacking on the two top shelves are physics books.
>   The books stacked on the two top shelves are physics books

Any ideas? And why?

Comment: Where did you find these sentences examples? Please cite the source. Please explain your confusion.  Do you not think it is possible to say the same thing in more than one way?

Answer (score 1):

Here, it's a question of agency and of process.

Looking at ongoing process first, "stacking" makes sense if the books continue to accumulate.   Do we expect more books to come in and stack themselves (or get themselves stacked) onto those shelves?   In other words, are we in the middle of a process that continues into the foreseeable future?   If so, the continuous aspect is justifiable.

We look at agency second because ergativity in English is complex, or at least less obvious than we'd like it to be.   When "John hits the ball", we know John is the agent and the ball is the patient.   However, when "flowers grow in the garden", are the flowers agents? patients? both? neither?   Do they act, or are they acted upon, and maybe do they act upon themselves?   It remains an open question.   Farmers grow wheat and corn, but wild flowers . . . simply . . . grow . . . .   Subject and object, agent and patient, are a confusing welter in this situation.

If the shelves have been stacked already, if we want to ignore the complexities of optional ergativity and we assume that the books that belong there are already there, then "stacked" is the natural choice.   We presume some unnamed agency did something, and we are done.   The physics books (by whatever agency) are stacked on those two shelves.

Answer (score 0):

As 'to stack' is a transitive verb, i.e., 'to stack books, boxes, packets, etc.', the only choice is 'books stacked /by somebody/'.
The other option is impossible, as the process of stacking can not be performed by books themselves.

Comment: Is saying "*The papers keep piling on my desk*" or "*I wish I had help to reduce the papers from piling on my desk*" incorrect, or ungrammatical?

Comment: To pile is an  intransitive verb. So both sentences  are correct.

Comment: If "pile" was an intransitive verb then the following sentence would be correct: "*They piled (what?) and left the classroom*".

Comment: Polysemy is highly developed in English. 'To pile' corresponds with people as subjects. Then we speak about the verb's 'transitivity'.